# Login Validation - error messages - always the same

Tags: django, django-authentication

I use the latest version of Django (2.05)

I created a custom user model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, MermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # can't login


class ULoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    # we declared this way to override the AuthenticationForm fields
    username = UsernameField(max_length=254, widget=TextWidget(attrs={'autofocus': True, 'placeholder': 'Email*'}))
    password = forms.CharField(strip=False, widget=PasswordWidget(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password*'}))
```

First, I can login if the credentials are correct, the issue is that in case of validation error I get the same message:

```
Please enter a correct email and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.
```

If the user/password are correct an account not active the message should be different, `account inactive`, to know the user that needs to confirm email.

After, further investigation in Django AutentificationForm it is the following code:

```
def clean:

      if username is not None and password:
                self.user_cache = authenticate(self.request, username=username, password=password)

                if self.user_cache is None:
                    raise forms.ValidationError(
                        self.error_messages['invalid_login'],
```

`self.user_cache` always return None and this seems to be the problem;

Comment: Did you write a custom login view? If not write one and check if the `is_active` attribute is `True`. If so log the user in if not write a custom response message.

Comment: Please print out the command that use to authenticate from the `views.py` file.

Comment: @hansTheFranz the user can login, please check again the question, I added more data to be clear

Comment: @PanosAngelopoulos - my View, just inherit from LoginView (Django class) I just update the html template